# Spark Streaming Bug - Window of Windowed DStream does not work

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Window of Windowed Dstream does not work in Spark Streaming. It seems a scheduler bug inside Spark Streaming.

```
val layer0= // Input data
val layer1 = layer0.window(Seconds(30), Seconds(30)) // Works
layer1.foreachRDD(...)

val layer2 = layer1.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(60)) // Does not work
layer2.foreachRDD(...)
```

Anyone met this issue, and get to know how to fix this in Spark.

Add more detail from the driver log:

**Time 1433141250000 ：**

2015-06-01 06:47:30 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141250000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 10000 ms

2015-06-01 06:47:30 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141250000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 60000 ms and difference is 10000 ms

**Time 1433141260000 :**

2015-06-01 06:47:40 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141260000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 20000 ms

2015-06-01 06:47:40 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141260000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 60000 ms and difference is 20000 ms

**Time 1433141270000 : (30S)**

2015-06-01 06:47:50 INFO  FilteredDStream - Slicing from 1433141250000 ms to 1433141270000 ms (aligned to 1433141250000 ms and 1433141270000 ms)

2015-06-01 06:47:50 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141270000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 60000 ms and difference is 30000 ms

**Time 1433141280000 :**
2015-06-01 06:48:00 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141280000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 40000 ms

2015-06-01 06:48:00 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141280000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 60000 ms and difference is 40000 ms

**Time 1433141290000 :**

2015-06-01 06:48:10 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141290000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 50000 ms

2015-06-01 06:48:10 INFO  MapValuedDStream - Time 1433141290000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 60000 ms and difference is 50000 ms

**Time 1433141300000 : (60S)**

2015-06-01 06:48:20 INFO  WindowedDStream - Slicing from 1433141270000 ms to 1433141300000 ms (aligned to 1433141250000 ms and 1433141280000 ms)

2015-06-01 06:48:20 INFO  WindowedDStream - Time 1433141250000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 10000 ms

2015-06-01 06:48:20 INFO  WindowedDStream - Time 1433141280000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1433141240000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 40000 ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bug and I've logged it as [SPARK-7326](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7326). I've also fixed it myself. See [my pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5871), which has been merged into master. I believe the fix will be in 1.4.0 release.

Comment: I am still facing this issue in Spark 1.6.1: 

16/11/22 19:46:30 INFO WindowedDStream: Time 1479824190000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1479824040000 ms and slideDuration is 300000 ms and difference is 150000 ms
16/11/22 19:46:30 INFO JobScheduler: No jobs added for time 1479824190000 ms